# How to edit or hide magento grand total section?

Tags: magento-1.9, totals, grand-total

My shopping cart grand total section appears as 2 X subtotal. in our store we are not charging any hidden charges or any extra taxes.

How to hide or edit grand total section? we want to show same subtotal value in grand total section

here i have attached a screenshot
[image]

Comment: If you're not in a production environment you can just switch on template path hints, in `admin->System->Configuration->Developer` then switch to a store view (below the Dashboard button) and in the Debug menu switch Template path hints to Yes.

Comment: i have enabled template path hints. check - http://new.shopping.lk/checkout/cart?tp=1&code=hints

Comment: Then if you go to your checkout page it will show you the template/layout which you will edit. frontend/em0132/default/template/checkout/cart/totals.phtml Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Totals

Comment: Which line should i edit?

here is the code - http://prntscr.com/8iqutq

Comment: The grand total part is in the renderTotals. One solution would be to replace this with your own custom code. Otherwise you can look in other files (e.g. template/tax/checkout/grandtotal.phtml) Another thing to say: don't edit the base/default code. Put the same file in your theme's path.

Answer (score -1):

first go to system->configuration->(left)current grand scope select to main website->advanced->developer->template path hints->yes->save config.
refresh the page then we can see the file paths. go to grand total file path and you can set to remove or hide grand total.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question